# How to read slice in Reflect.FieldByName()

Tags: go

I pass data to a func with input type interface.

This code:

```
main(){
    SampleData := Input{
    Recipients: []string{"abc","efg"},
    Msg:        string("Test message"),
    }
    InsertInSendTBL(SampleData)
}

type Input struct {
    Recipients []string
    Msg        string
    sender      string
}
type Output struct {
    Recipients    []string
    Msg           string
    reciver     string
}
func InsertInSendTBL(Data interface{}) {
    DataInput := reflect.ValueOf(Data)
    NewVal := Output{
        Recipients: DataInput.FieldByName("Recipients").([]string{}),//LINE ERORE
        Msg:        DataInput.FieldByName("Msg").String(),
        sender:     "1000",
    }
}
```

One of my struct fields is slice of string. I searched in reflect package but not found anything so I use ".([]string{})" .
Result is this error:

> invalid type assertion: DataInput.FieldByName("Recipients").(composite literal) (non-interface type reflect.Value on left)

so I try interface in reflect But another error

> cannot use DataInput.FieldByName("Recipients").Interface() (type interface {}) as type []string in field value: need type assertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to combine your two attempts:

```
sliceOfString, ok := DataInput.FieldByName("Recipients").Interface().([]string)
if !ok {
    panic("Not a []string!")
}
```